# awk remove endings of words ending with patterns

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a large dataset and am trying to lemmatize a column ($14) with awk, which is I need to remove 'ing', 'ed', 's' in words if it ends with one of those pattern. So asked, asks, asking would be just 'ask' after all.

Let's say I have this dataset (the column I want to make modifications is $2:

```
onething      This is a string that is tested multiple times.
twoed         I wanted to remove words ending with many patterns.
threes        Reading books is good thing.
```

With that, expected output is:

```
onething      Thi i a str that i test multiple time.
twoed         I want to remove word end with many pattern.
threes        Read book i good th.
```

I have tried following regex with awk, but it didnt work.

```
awk -F'\t' '{gsub(/\(ing|ed|s\)\b/," ",$2); print}' file.txt  

#this replaces some of the words with ing and ed, not all, words ending with s stays the same (which I dont want)
```

Please help, I'm new to awk and still exploring it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `gensub()` and `\>` for word boundaries:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$2=gensub(/(ing|ed|s)\>/,"","g",$2)} 1' file
onething        Thi i a str that i test multiple time.
twoed   I want to remove word end with many pattern.
threes  Read book i good th.
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Your code doesn't work for me but I modified it a little bit and it worked.

Comment: It does exactly what you asked for and, as you can see in my answer, produced the output you wanted from the input you provided so - in what way does it not work for you and in what way did you modify it?

Comment: Anyway, you're welcome, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk for what to do next.

Comment: the only thing I changed was the BEGIN part: `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}`, I dont think it was much different from yours. Thank you!!

Comment: What you did only changed from the right way to do it that I have in my script (assigning both variables together to a single value) to the wrong way to do it (assigning each variable separately to the same value) from a maintenance perspective but it didn't make any functional difference. If that's the only change you made and what you had after doing that worked then the script I posted also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using any `awk` with `gsub` you could do:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '
    { gsub(/(s|ed|ing)[.[:blank:]]/," ",$2)
      match($2,/[.]$/) || sub(/[[:blank:]]$/,".",$2)
    }1
' file
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
onething        This is a string that is tested multiple times.
twoed   I wanted to remove words ending with many patterns.
threes  Reading books is good thing.
four    Just a normal sentence.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '
>     { gsub(/(s|ed|ing)[.[:blank:]]/," ",$2)
>       match($2,/[.]$/) || sub(/[[:blank:]]$/,".",$2)
>     }1
> ' file
onething        Thi i a str that i test multiple time.
twoed   I want to remove word end with many pattern.
threes  Read book i good th.
four    Just a normal sentence.
```

(**note:** last line added as example of a sentence unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU awk you were not far from it:

```sh
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/ing|ed|s\>/,"",$2); print}' file.txt
onething    Thi i a str that i test multiple time.
twoed   I want to remove word end with many pattern.
threes  Read book i good th.
```

Note `-v OFS='\t'` to use tabs also as output field separators.

But if your awk uses the kind of obsolete regular expressions without word boundaries (like the default awk that comes with macOS) things are more complicated. One option is to iteratively use `match` and `substr`. Example:

```
# foo.awk
BEGIN {
  n = split(prefix, word, /,/)
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    len[i] = length(word[i])
  }
}
{
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    re = word[i] "[^[:alnum:]]"
    while(m = match($2, re)) {
      if(m == 1) {
        $2 = substr($2, len[i]+1, length($2))
      } else {
      $2 = substr($2, 1, m-1) substr($2, m+len[i], length($2))
      }
    }
  }
  print
}
```

And then:

```sh
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' -v prefix="ing,ed,s" -f foo.awk file.txt
onething    Thi i a str that i test multiple time.
twoed   I want to remove word end with many pattern.
threes  Read book i good th.
```